How big is the magnitude of the $\vec{B}$ field inside a wire that generates it?
If a wire with current generates a magnetic field, what is the magnitude of this $\vec{B}$ field inside the wire?
Example: an idealized solenoid traversed by a fixed current has $\vec{B}$ uniform inside of it and $\vec{B}=0$ outside. Can we be talking about Laplace forces in this wire, considering that the wire is on a $\vec{B}=0$ zone and at the same time on a $\vec{B}= \text{Constante}$ zone?
The answer probably lies in the fact that wire has some thickness. In our above example, if we mentally "split" our wire into an external half and an interior half, we have that the external half generates a uniform $\vec{B}$ field in the interior of the solenoid (which now encompasses the interior half of the wire). We conclude that at least the interior half is immersed in a magnetic field.
Is this way of reasoning right?
Also, professor introduced this magnetic field lines graph of "a magnetic dipole".
I don't quite know if it represents a circular wire traversed by a current, or a permanent magnet, but one can notice that the $\vec{B}$ field seems to be equal to zero in the middle of the upper side of the yellow rectangle (where the lines make a kind of small triangular path).
Am I interpreting right the field lines graph?
If so, and if we suppose that the graph represents a circular wire, does that mean that the field is equal to zero in the exact location of the wire?


This depends on the magnetic permeability $\mu$ of the material. The $\vec{H}$ field is what one would naturally use to talk about the magnetic field inside a magnetic material. If you've studied electrostatics in dielectric media, you'll see the relationship between the two magnetic field is similar to that of the electric field and the electric displacement field. It is
$$\vec{B}=\mu\vec{H}, $$
where the magnetic permeability $\mu$ isn't necessarily a scalar, but for our purposes let's consider it as one. Ultimately, this all comes from the fact that bound currents are related to the magnetization of a material, in particular
$$\nabla \times \vec{M}=\vec{J}_{\mathrm{bound}}. $$
And so, in Maxwell's equations
$$\nabla \times \vec{B}=\mu_0\vec{J}_{\mathrm{free}}+\mu_0\nabla\times\vec{M} \to \nabla\times\left(\frac{\vec{B}}{\mu_0}-\vec{M} \right) =\vec{J}_{\mathrm{free}} \to \vec{H}= \frac{\vec{B}}{\mu_0}-\vec{M}. $$
The magnetic permeability appears when you consider that the magnetization is linear with the magnetic field, that is $\vec{M}=\chi_m\vec{H}$ where $\chi_m$ is the magnetic susceptibility. Then
$$\vec{H}=\frac{\mu}{\mu_0}\vec{H}-\chi_m\vec{H} \to \mu = \mu_0 (1+\chi_m).$$
The scalar relation follows for linear and isotropic materials. So, how does one determine $\vec{B}$ inside the material? Well, in a simple approach one would assume $\nabla \cdot \vec{M}=0$ so that $\nabla\cdot \vec{H}=0$. That means that you could apply Ampère's law and determine the $H$ field through simple symmetry arguments, for example. The $\vec{H}$ field is the same throughout the entire region of interest, inside or outside the material. You just multiply it by $\mu$ inside the material to find the $\vec{B}$ inside, or by $\mu_0$ to find it outside (assuming the outer region is a vacuum).

If the wire has a finite thickness, then you need a model for the current density within the wire.
Typically you might assume a uniform current density, in which case application of Ampere's law for an individual wire, in the form
$$\oint \vec{B}\cdot d\vec{l} = \mu_0 \int \vec{J}\cdot d\vec{A}$$
$$2\pi r B = \pi r^2 \mu_0 J$$
shows that the B-field increases linearly from zero at the centre of the wire to a maximum its outer radius.
This assumes the wire is long and has a circular cross-section.
